# Selecting row and deleting doesn't delete row

Tags: vba, excel

I've written some simple code that matches cells in one worksheet to cells in another, and then deletes the entire row if the cells are equal.

The code selects rows properly, but for some reason refuses to actually delete the rows in my worksheet. EDIT: Some of the rows delete. Others don't, even though they have the exact same values as those that did delete. If anyone can help that would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub delFunds()
Dim fCell As Range 'Fund cell
Dim fRng As Range 'Fund range
Dim wCell As Range 'Working sheet cell
Dim wRng As Range 'Working sheet range
Dim n As Long

Set fRng = Worksheets("Funds").Range("C2:C117")
Set wRng = Worksheets("Working sheet").Range("I3:I7483")

For Each fCell In fRng.Cells 'Loop through all funds
    For Each wCell In wRng.Cells 'Loop through all working cells
        If StrComp(wCell.Value, fCell.Value, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then 'If equal then delete
            n = wCell.Row
            Rows(n & ":" & n).Select
            Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
        End If
    Next wCell
Next fCell 'Go to next fund

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you need to operate on the row itself, or can you just work with the `wCell` range? Would `wCell.EntireRow.Delete` work in the context of your entire script?

Comment: I need the actual row to be deleted. Doing wCell.EntireRow.Delete doesn't actually delete the row that the cell is in either ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use this code without nested loop:

```
Sub delFunds()
    Dim rngToDel As Range 
    Dim fRng As Range 'Fund range
    Dim wCell As Range 'Working sheet cell
    Dim wRng As Range 'Working sheet range

    Set fRng = Worksheets("Funds").Range("C2:C117")
    Set wRng = Worksheets("Working sheet").Range("I3:I7483")

    For Each wCell In wRng 'Loop through all working cells
        ' if wCell found in Fund range then delete row
        If Not IsError(Application.Match(Trim(wCell.Value), fRng, 0)) Then
            If rngToDel Is Nothing Then
                Set rngToDel = wCell
            Else
                Set rngToDel = Union(rngToDel, wCell)
            End If
        End If
    Next wCell

    If Not rngToDel Is Nothing Then rngToDel.EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

Comment: For some reason, your solution worked. Any idea why?

Comment: I can explain why _your_ solution doesn't work:) the problem is that when you delete row in loop, your loop becomes skewed. E.g. if you delete row 3 _in loop_, then `1)` row 4 shifts up and becomes row 3 `2)` in next iteration your `wCell` would be "incremented" and would refers to row 4, but not to row 3 (this row 3 previously was row 4 and you haven't examened it)

Answer (score 2):

I know @simoco's answer works and has been accepted already, but I love a good question so I wanted to pull together a solution using the `autofilter` to kill big swaths of the working sheet at once. I figured your design might look like this:

[image: setup]

From there, you can loop through the concise fund list and filter the working sheet on each fund:

```
Option Explicit
Sub EliminateWorkingDuplicates()

Dim WorkingSheet As Worksheet, FundSheet As Worksheet
Dim FundRange As Range, WorkingRange As Range, _
    Fund As Range
Dim LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long, _
    WorkingFundCol As Long

'assign sheets and ranges for easy reference
Set WorkingSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Working sheet")
Set FundSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Funds")
Set FundRange = FundSheet.Range("C2:C117")
WorkingFundCol = 9 'column I on working sheet

'determine the bounds of the data block on the working sheet
LastRow = WorkingSheet.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
LastCol = WorkingSheet.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
Set WorkingRange = Range(WorkingSheet.Cells(2, 1), WorkingSheet.Cells(LastRow, LastCol))

'start working through the funds and calling the autofilter function
For Each Fund In FundRange
    Call FilterAndDeleteData(WorkingRange, WorkingFundCol, Fund.Value)
    Call ClearAllFilters(WorkingSheet)
Next Fund

End Sub

'**********
'blow away rows
Sub FilterAndDeleteData(DataBlock As Range, TargetColumn As Long, Criteria As String)

'make sure some joker didn't pass in an empty range
If DataBlock Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

'execute the autofilter with the supplied column and criteria
With DataBlock
    .AutoFilter Field:=TargetColumn, Criteria1:=Criteria
    .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
End With

End Sub

'**********
'safely clear filters
Sub ClearAllFilters(TargetSheet As Worksheet)

With TargetSheet
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    If .FilterMode = True Then
        .ShowAllData
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: +1 for autofilter, however it seems to me that in this particular case this solution can be _very_ slow.. You should apply filter 115 times for range with 7500 rows. And if OP's working worksheet contains a lot of formulas, autofilter would be even slower, since it fires sheet recalculation each time it applies

Comment: Great point -- I hadn't considered the induced calculation for every `autofilter` application. Off-hand, do you know if that can be mitigated with the old stand-by, `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual`?